# GAN with additional custom loss function

Tags: python, keras, reshape, loss, generative-adversarial-network

The following shows a standard GAN model:

```
def define_gan(g_model, d_model, image_shape):
    # make weights in the discriminator not trainable
    d_model.trainable = False
    # define the source image
    in_src = Input(shape=image_shape)
    # connect the source image to the generator input
    gen_out = g_model(in_src)
    # connect the source input and generator output to the discriminator input
    dis_out = d_model([in_src, gen_out])
    # src image as input, generated image and classification output
    model = Model(in_src, [dis_out, gen_out])
    # compile model
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'mae'], optimizer=opt, loss_weights=[1,100])
    return model
```

I want to add an extra loss to the model as follows:

```
def define_gan(g_model, d_model, image_shape, p_model):
    # make weights in the discriminator not trainable
    d_model.trainable = False
    # define the source image
    in_src = Input(shape=image_shape)
    # connect the source image to the generator input
    gen_out = g_model(in_src)
    # connect the source input and generator output to the discriminator input
    dis_out = d_model([in_src, gen_out])
    # connect the p output to the generator output
    p_out = p_model(gen_out)
    # src image as input, generated image and classification output
    model = Model(in_src, [dis_out, gen_out, p_out])
    # compile model
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
    model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'mae', 'mse'], optimizer=opt, loss_weights=[1,100,100])
    return model
```

As can been seen, I added the p model, which is not actually a keras model. It is a function that takes the generated output by gan_out and compares it with some other model to measure the extra loss. A small part of the function is as follows:

```
def define_p(image_shape):
    in_image = Input(shape=image_shape)
    u1 = np.reshape(in_image[:,:,0], (N))
    u2 = np.reshape(in_image[:,:,1], (N))
    u3 = np.reshape(in_image[:,:,2], (N))
    # compute two specific matrices (M, N) based on u1, u2, u3
    # ...
    out_image = M - N
    model = Model(in_image, out_image)
    return model
```

The main problem I am facing is that the in_image is of dimension (?,64,64,3) and I cannot reshape it and then do operation on each u1, u2, u3 separately for each batch. Any help is highly appreciated!